# error when when building boost with b2.exe and intel compiler (intel-19.1)

Tags: boost, icc

I am using Intel OneAPI 2021 with VS2019

This is the command I run

```
.\b2 toolset="intel-19.1" address-model=64 threading=multi runtime-link=static link=static variant=release
```

This is the error below

```
F:/Projects/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/tools\intel-win.jam:172: in configure-really
*** argument error
* rule path.make ( native )
* called with: (  )
* missing argument native
F:/Projects/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/util\path.jam:518:see definition of rule 'path.make' being called
F:/Projects/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/tools\intel-win.jam:132: in configure
F:/Projects/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/tools\intel-win.jam:46: in intel-win.init
F:/Projects/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/build\toolset.jam:44: in toolset.using
F:/Projects/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/tools\intel.jam:82: in intel.init
F:/Projects/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/build\toolset.jam:44: in toolset.using
F:/Projects/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:543: in process-explicit-toolset-requests
F:/Projects/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:610: in load
F:/Projects/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import
F:/Projects/boost_1_73_0/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
F:/Projects/boost_1_73_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use latest boost library (1.76 beta). The configuration files for building boost 1.73 doesn't work with Intel Compiler.